# Wavewatch III data

Tags: models, wind, waves, database

I need to simulate some ocean data on the south coast of France, near to Marseilles. Ideally I am looking for parameters such as wind direction, wind speed, significant wave height, peak wave period and the mean wave direction.

I have been looking at the WW3 data on http://polar.ncep.noaa.gov/waves/download.shtml but the resolution for this area is only 0.5 degrees.

I am looking for data of a higher resolution so I wanted to know if anyone knows of either:
- any place that stores this kind of data
- how to go about simulating my own WW3 data

I can get ASCAT data for the wind direction/wind speed but they don't provide the ocean wave parameters.

Comment: Just an idea: ask someone at *Meteo France*? If I needed such data for the German coast, I would ask someone (maybe get connected via a colleague) at the German Weather Service (DWD) or den Federal Maritime and Hydrographic Agency (BSH).

Comment: I have managed to get some from a similar source - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Look at the answer to https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/10154/sources-of-weather-data/10155 under the 'The "raw" data as it comes into NOAA from airports, surface weather stations, boats, and buoys'. Is that what you seek?

Note that I couldn't get your link to download, though this may just be a temporary NOAA glitch.

Comment: That is not a source for wavewatch III model resulsts

Comment: Thanks for your answer - the parameters are for weather forecasts/hidcasts though as opposed to ocean parameters